# What does X-Cache: Hit from Backend mean?

Tags: php, http, http-headers, symfony, xcache

I looked all over the internet but can't seem to find out what this means.  I think it might be the cause of an error I'm currently getting in which the page refuses to update its references to certain files in my symfony application.

[image]

I looked into X-Cache but I do not have it installed on my system, I'm using OpCache though.

[image]

Comment: The `X-*` prefix is normally used to indicate non-standard http header fields. Look at the header fields sent by SO. I have `X-Frame-Options` and `X-Request-Guid`. I think that it does not belong to XCache as a software, rather that _some_ caching software scored a hit. Anyway, do you have any error with your current setup?

Comment: Also, one minute of googling revealed this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027492/x-cache-header-explanation

Comment: Joshua that actually does not answer the question, because I'm looking for what Hit from Backend means, Hit means it came from CDN not sure what it means when it says backend like that.  I actually read that before posting this also, I should have linked it.

Comment: As for my current setup I was finally able to fix the issue, but still not sure what that hit from back-end means? I was able to fix my issue through some symfony cache clearing techniques.  I suppose if you try to dump assetic assets and there is an error during that process it doesn't clear cache correctly even though 'it looked like it did', especially on localhost, and that is probably why x-cache header came into play.

Comment: Since X-* prefix means it a non-standard http field, question is does that particular X-cache field mean something to the Google Chrome Browser from which I used at the time, and did that store on my local computer somehow the cache files? I was using localhost when I did this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link, http://ageekandhisblog.com/cloudflare-the-cdn-that-saves-your-server/.
In short you see this header because CloudFlare is on.

Comment: That link does not answer the question: It only mentions the phrase "HIT from Backend" once and does not explain it at all.

Comment: There is a cache server in place, in this case it is CloudFlare. if you request a resource which has been cached with cache server and it serves cached version you will see this header.